# Is there a way to ignore / cancel a specific fish shell completion while typing?

Tags: fish

Fish shell is awesome, and its completions is one of the reasons I love it so much.

But, every once in a while, when I type I get a completion that's not useful for me. The problem is the completion replaces what I wrote, and so I don't know how to continue.

Here's an example:

```sh
$ touch HELLO
$ echo goodbye > h
```

When I type the last letter, `h`, fish shell replaces it with `HELLO` where the capital `H` is already typed, and the `ELLO` part is grayed out, meaning that it will be replaced by future typing.
But I just wanted to create a file named `h` with the content `goodbye` - fish gives me a hard time :(

Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not replace what you typed. The effective string is still "h", so just pressing enter will create a file called "h".

(yes, this could be shown better, there is an open issue about it)

Comment: That's good to know! However, is there a way to also reflect that in the command line - like pressing `ESC` or something (tried, it didn't work) so that it shows `h`?

Comment: No, there currently is not. That's why there's an open issue about it. However, the commandline will include what you typed. If you typed a lowercase "h", it'll have a lowercase "h". Fish only replaces it if you accept the suggestion (with e.g. right-arrow) or do a completion (with tab).